# Selenium with capybara can't sign in/up with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, devise

I am trying to pass the sign in or sign-up test using rspec. All configuration works fine, all previous integration tests passed.

Spec code below:

```
visit "/"
save_and_open_page
expect(page).to have_no_selector '#register-dialog'

find(:css, 'a.button.signup').click
expect(page).to have_selector '#register-dialog'
fill_in 'customer_name', with: "abcde"
fill_in 'customer_email', with: "name@email.com"
fill_in 'customer_password', with: "abcdef"
find(:css, "input#customer_terms").set(true)
find(:css, 'input[type=\'submit\']').click

expect(page).to have_no_selector '#register-dialog'
expect(page).to have_selector '#after-register' # fails
# expected to find css "#after-register" but there were no matches
```

I check that last steps create a Customer user in test database, **but can't automatically sign in**.

The question is **why?** In development environment all works ok.

I use database cleaner, config is below:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_examples = false
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.around(:each) do |spec|
    if spec.metadata[:js] || spec.metadata[:test_commit]
      spec.run
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      spec.run
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:rollback_transaction_records, true)
      rescue
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to sign in/up with devise helpers, but no luck.

Comment: How do you know the test isn't signing in? I don't see any assertions. Add more info to your question.

Comment: I use sleep() function after it and check webpage state manually. All assertions for check messages status ("successfull sign in" etc.) fails.

Comment: Could you post the test, the test output and then try save_and_open_page to see the result of the root (check input fields and their ids etc), as well as the result after clicking submit?

Comment: @HannesFostie - updated with save_and_open_page

Comment: At the line before `expect(page).to have_selector '#after-register' # fails`, you can output message `p page.body` to see what error your page is throwing. This will give you more insights into why there is an error.

Comment: At this moment, I know that session cookie is not set properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the core of the problem:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', expire_after: 7.days, domain: {
  ...
  test: AppConfig.host_name
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)
```

The `host_name` for test env was different than selenium server host, so `session_cookie` was not set.

Comment: Could you explain how do I set then host for test env to be equal to selenium host?